# How can I spilt element to different columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a python program to output a dataset of ranking of some items.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

list=[{'ranking': 1, 'sku': 'WD-0215', 'name': 'Sofa', 'price': '$1,299.00', 'detail': 'Red'}, 
      {'ranking': 1, 'sku': 'WD-0215', 'name': 'Sofa', 'price': '$1,299.00', 'detail': 'Cottom'},
      {'ranking': 1, 'sku': 'WD-0215', 'name': 'Sofa', 'price': '$1,299.00', 'detail': 'Wood Lab'},
      {'ranking': 2, 'sku': 'sfr20', 'name': 'TV', 'price': '$1,861.00 – $3,699.00', 'detail': 'W1360×D750×H710'},
      {'ranking': 2, 'sku': 'sfr20', 'name': 'TV', 'price': '$1,861.00 – $3,699.00', 'detail': 'LED'}, 
      {'ranking': 2, 'sku': 'sfr20', 'name': 'TV', 'price': '$1,861.00 – $3,699.00', 'detail': 'Made in Japan'},
      {'ranking': 2, 'sku': 'sfr20', 'name': 'TV', 'price': '$1,861.00 – $3,699.00', 'detail': 'Nordic'}
     ]

df = pd.DataFrame(list)
print(df)
df.to_csv('item.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

However my expected output should be like this:

| ranking | sku | name | price | detail1 | detail2 | detail3 | detail4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WD-0215 | Sofa | $1299.00 | Red | Cottom | Wood Lab | none |
| 1 | sfr20 | TV | $1861.00-$3699.00 | W1360×D750×H710 | LED | Made in Japan | Nordic |

How can change the code to ouput this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['ranking', 'sku', 'name', 'price']).cumcount().add(1)

df = df.set_index(['ranking', 'sku', 'name', 'price', g])['detail'].unstack().add_prefix('detail')
print (df)
                                                    detail1 detail2  \
ranking sku     name price                                            
1       WD-0215 Sofa $1,299.00                          Red  Cottom   
2       sfr20   TV   $1,861.00 – $3,699.00  W1360×D750×H710     LED   

                                                  detail3 detail4  
ranking sku     name price                                         
1       WD-0215 Sofa $1,299.00                   Wood Lab     NaN  
2       sfr20   TV   $1,861.00 – $3,699.00  Made in Japan  Nordic
```