# Stack rows over two columns

Tags: python, pandas

i want to stack the rows with the same ID and OP Date in one row toghether.

Source:

| ID | OP Date | OP Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | X1 |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | X2 |
| 1 | 02.01.2021 | X3 |
| 2 | 03.01.2021 | X4 |
| 2 | 03.01.2021 | X5 |
| 3 | 04.01.2021 | X6 |
| 3 | 04.01.2021 | X7 |
| 3 | 04.01.2021 | X8 |
| 3 | 05.01.2021 | X9 |
| 3 | 05.01.2021 | X10 |

Desiered Outcome:

| ID | OP Date | OP Code | OP Code_2 | OP Code_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | X1 | X2 |  |
| 1 | 02.01.2021 | X3 |  |  |
| 2 | 03.01.2021 | X4 | X5 |  |
| 3 | 04.01.2021 | X6 | X7 | X8 |
| 3 | 05.01.2021 | X9 | X10 |  |

How can i do this operation in Pandas or with another tools in Python?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Chck [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68015603/2901002) solution, only change `['ranking', 'sku', 'name', 'price']`  to `['ID', 'OP Date']`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
data=[{"id": 1, "OP Date": "01.01.2021", "OP Code": "X1"},
       {"id": 1, "OP Date": "01.01.2021", "OP Code": "X2"}]
parsed_ops = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    parsed_ops[f'{item["id"]}_{item["OP Date"]}'].append(item["OP Code"])

parsed_data=[]
for key, value in parsed_ops.items():
    parsed = {"id": f'{key.split("_")[0]}', "OP Date": f'{key.split("_")[1]}'}
    for index, op in enumerate(value, start=1):
        parsed[f"OP Code_{index}"]=op
    parsed_data.append(parsed)
pd.DataFrame(parsed_data)
```

Output:

```
  id     OP Date OP Code_1 OP Code_2
0  1  01.01.2021        X1        X2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68017780/stack-rows-over-two-columns#comment120219343_68017780

Comment: @jezrael Saw that nice indeed.
The above solution can be a native solution.